# create list and generate descriptives for each variable

Tags: r, list, loops, datatable

I want to generate descriptive statistics for multiple variables at a time (close to 50), rather than writing out the code several times.

Here is a very basic example of data:

```
id   var1   var2
1     1      3
2     2      3
3     1      4
4     2      4
```

I typically write out each line of code to get a frequency count and descriptives, like so:

```
library(psych)

table(df$var1)
table(df1$var2)
describe(df1$var1)
describe(df1$var2)
```

I would like to create a list and get the output from these analyses, rather than writing out 100 lines of code. I tried this, but it is not working:

```
variable_list<-list(df1$var, df2$var)

for (variable in variable_list){
table(df$variable_list))
describe(df$variable_list))}
```

Does anyone have advice on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `describe` from `psych` can take a `data.frame` and returns the descriptive statistics for each column

```
library(psych)
describe(df1)
#     vars n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
#id      1 4  2.5 1.29    2.5     2.5 1.48   1   4     3    0    -2.08 0.65
#var1    2 4  1.5 0.58    1.5     1.5 0.74   1   2     1    0    -2.44 0.29
#var2    3 4  3.5 0.58    3.5     3.5 0.74   3   4     1    0    -2.44 0.29
```

If it is subset of columns, specify either column index or column name to select and subset the dataset

```
describe(df1[2:3])
```

---

Another option is `descr` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
descr(slt(df1, 2:3))
```

Or to select numeric columns

```
descr(num_vars(df1))
```

Or for `factors`

```
descr(fact_vars(df1))
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. I don't want to do the entire df, just several variables. I guess you're suggesting create a new df with just those variables?

Comment: That's easy enough to do.